# git-svn on Windows. Where to get binaries?

Tags: windows, svn, git

I want to use git as a local repository against a remote SVN repository. I installed version 1.6.0.2 from http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list.

According to the documentation synchronization is done via the command

```
git svn
```

or a separate command wrapper called

```
git-svn
```

Neither of them is available in my installation and I could not find a separate download for Windows binaries.

I'm currenty using the MSYS build. Must I switch to cygwin?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[This earlier version](http://msysgit.googlecode.com/files/Git-1.5.5-preview20080413.exe) has working git-svn. I thought that git-svn in the current version that you installed was fixed, but maybe not.  Git-svn definitely did not work in the windows version of Git 1.5.6.1.

Comment: git-svn has been added back it latest versions

Comment: @RaulGuiu yep, you were right, the link is now dead

Answer (score 39):

git-svn is installed in the latest version of msysgit. However, there's a slight caveat: while git-svn shows up in C:\Program Files\git\libexec as "git-svn", svn is actually called as an argument to the git executable, thus:

```
git svn clone http://example.com/svn/repo/
```

Answer (score 11):

Install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) and select the git-svn package under the Devel category.

Answer (score 5):

The `git svn` command is written in Perl and requires the Subversion Perl libraries. The existence of the `svn` command line command is insufficient for `git-svn`.

I haven't used `git svn` on Windows (only on Unix and Mac OS X), so I can't really provide more detail, but hopefully this should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know git, but I know that for Mercurial, for example, you have to have SVN installed to convert from SVN to Mercurial (and back). Perhaps it is the same for git?

SVN is quite big by itself, so perhaps concurrent systems won't want to distribute it with their software, bloating the download.

I used the command line SVN client from [Slik SVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/), not too big and installing cleanly.

Of course, wait for more informed answer, or search the Web for confirmation of my information... :-) Although it doesn't hurt to have an SVN client, since lot of projects use it.

Comment: Hi, that's an interesting point I haven't thought of, thanks. But I actually have both svn command line client from tigris and TortoiseSVN on my system (and path), so it doesn't seem to be the problem :-/