# Git and SVN on Windows

Tags: svn, git, msysgit

I'm trying to run git for my local repository and use SVN for my central repository to a CodePlex project. I downloaded the most recent version of [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list), but the SVN support doesn't appear to be working.

The following successfully initializes a new empty repository and then gets stuck:

```
git svn init https://myproject.svn.codeplex.com
git svn fetch
```

After attempting to perform the fetch, I get the following:

```
Error validating server certificate for 'https://myproject.svn.codeplex.com:443'
:
 - The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority. Use the
   fingerprint to validate the certificate manually!
Certificate information:
 - Hostname: *.svn.codeplex.com
 - Valid: from May 23 02:11:05 2009 GMT until May 23 02:11:05 2010 GMT
 - Issuer: redmond, corp, microsoft, com
 - Fingerprint: f0:89:78:18:47:70:e4:dc:27:01:27:9c:6f:44:4c:3f:8a:9b:ad:79
(R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently? p
```

As you can see, I try to permanently accept the certificate, but msysgit just sits and never performs the fetch.

Am I doing something wrong? Is the support not there? I found a similar [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350907/git-svn-on-windows-where-to-get-binaries) from December. I'm not sure if the symptoms I'm experiencing are the same, or not.

Comment: 5 -1/2 years later and I still get this error. I wonder how many OSS projects stay dead because they can't be cloned? Yes, I know you can download the zip but sheesh, really?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure why, but it takes a pretty long time to come back from the prompt above that asks whether or not to accept the certificate. After waiting about 15 minutes, the operation did complete.

Comment: I've left it running for the whole night. It timed out somewhere in between. No luck with waiting here. Also strangely the Source Code page for the project that I try to checkout is very slow (takes up to 1 minute to load the page). Also I know that the project author is actually using TeamServer for the backend. Here is the project: https://v8dotnet.codeplex.com/. My goal is to fork it to GitHub. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @SergiyByelozyorov yeah, that site is pretty messed up. It started cloning for me, but didn't make it very far. I'd contact the maintainers or somebody on CodePlex to see what's up with it. git-svn isn't going to work if the backend host is having issues.

Comment: Open Windows Resource Monitor and look at the network traffic. Perl.exe is the git-svn executable. If there's bytes then it may just be working. Maybe.

Answer (score 3):

git-svn does not work well on windows in my experience. What I would advise is to put your git import on something like github or any other git hosting, and use "pure" git on windows. This assumes you have a unix (or at worse cygwin, which should work better than msysgit I guess) to do the git-svn updates. That's not ideal, obviously.

Comment: I get exactly the same response, using git-svn on both Mac OSX 10.6.5 and Ubuntu 10.04, accessing Codeplex-based SVN repositories, so this doesn't appear to be a windows-only problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by adding the certificates to the auth-chain.
You have to get the issuer-certificate (CA) of your server-certificate in .pem-format and copy it to the certs-directory (PATH_TO_GIT\ssl\certs) with a hashed name.
Generate the hash like so:

```
C:\> PATH_TO_GIT\bin\openssl.exe x509 -noout -hash -in PATH_TO_CA_CERT.PEM
```

Rename the CA-file to the output of the command and add ".0" as extension (e.g. 0dbd0096.0). This way openssl find the CA wich can be used to certify your server-certificate.

Find more information here: http://gagravarr.org/writing/openssl-certs/others.shtml#ca-openssl

Answer (score 1):

Codeplex and SVN are as slow as they are archaic. Here is what worked for me (different project buy you get the idea)

```
git svn clone https://iswix.svn.codeplex.com/svn -r42691:HEAD
```

where 42691 was the oldest changeset in the repo (or the oldest one you want to fetch) and HEAD is ...duh, the head.

I found the changeset number by looking at the [history tab in the source code page](https://iswix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets?size=100). It's the last one.

I tried all sorts of settings with TortoiseGit but it wouldn't play, command line or bust.

Now go make a cup of tea or bake a cake, it will take quite some time.

If (on Windows) you open the Resource Monitor and look for perl.exe under "network" and see it is talking to svn.codeplex.com then it is working.

Answer (score -3):

use http without ssl.
I use fetch from sourceforge https://xmlvm.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/xmlvm/
encomes this issue,and I just change url to http://xmlvm.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/xmlvm/
It works fine

Comment: Sometimes you just can or are not willing to use plain http and are in need for a working https-connection.

Comment: CodePlex doesn't support plain http for SVN.