# Cloning SVN repository for Git

Tags: git, svn, msysgit, git-extensions

I'm using SVN for source control which is hosted by a repository hosting company. I'm considering migrating this to Git and testing the waters of migration by trying to migrate to a local Git instance. I've installed Git Extensions v2.31 and installed the msysgit version that I was offered during the installation.

Once installed, I then clicked on the 'Clone SVN repository' option and entered in the SVN repo location and other necessary details. Clicked on the Clone button. I was then presented with the following message in the Process output window (I've desensitised some info):

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe svn clone "https://foobar.domain.com/folder/name.svn" "c:/git/"
Initialized empty Git repository in c:/git/.git/
Error validating server certificate for 'https://foobar.domain.com:443':
 - The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority. Use the
   fingerprint to validate the certificate manually!
Certificate information:
 - Hostname: *.domain.com
 - Valid: from Mar 18 13:23:06 2012 GMT until Apr 20 16:16:05 2013 GMT
 - Issuer: GeoTrust, Inc., US
 - Fingerprint: a2:36:f0:ae:8c:c7:a3:f2:be:98:b3:0f:2e:f8:3a:07:9a:94:90:81
```

At this point nothing else gets displayed, the progress bar is still indicating progress but nothing really happens. The issue seems similar to what is reported here: [Git and SVN on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239577/git-and-svn-on-windows)

However, I do not even get the option to reject/accept etc? Anyone got any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recomment you to try clone with [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/index.html). Is has it's based on another engine, not git-svn or even SVN, so I think you won't get this problem. There're some more reasons to prefer SmartGit: it translates such SVN concepts like branches, tags, ignores, EOLs to the corresponding Git concepts, git-svn doesn't.

Answer (score 9):

You can still do this with Git Extensions. Open Git Bash from inside Git Extensions and run the command you saw it produce when using the GUI: `git svn clone "https://foobar.domain.com/folder/name.svn" "c:/git/"` This will provide you with the reject/accept temporarily/permanently options you see in the other SO question you linked to.

If you've already tried the "Clone SVN Repository" option and never saw success as described, your local repo is actually already set up, just not populated with any of the files yet. In this case, you no longer need to do a clone, just a fetch. Running `git svn fetch` on the project you tried to clone will also provide you with the reject/accept/etc options.

Comment: When using Git Bash you can permanently accept the certificate and then go back to use Git Extensions (or TortoiseGit).

Comment: I much prefer adding "svn" to the git clone command so I believe this answer is the best one provided.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using terminal and understand better how git works, I suggest you to use [git bash](http://msysgit.github.io/). Otherwise you should use [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/index.html) by syntevo, because it also offers a different engine and key managements and, IMPO, it's the best GUI tool in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html). Its SVN integration supports more features than *git-svn* and it's built upon a different SVN client library which usually handles the various authentication scenarios quite well.