# using git to clone a CodePlex project that uses SVN

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, codeplex

I have a project hosted in CodePlex, I chose SVN when I created this project.
Now I try to use Git to clone this project.

I tried: "git svn clone the_url"

But it just hangs forever. It did not ask me for username or password or anything, just hangs.

Any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: Are you able to checkout the code from that location via SVN?

Comment: What command do you use for the SVN co?

Comment: Does the URL start with http(s):// or svn://

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239577/git-and-svn-on-windows

Comment: 2015 and SVN on Codeplex still sucks. That would explain the tumbleweeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239577/git-and-svn-on-windows) regarding git svn and CodePlex.  There are multiple possibilities, including SSL certificates, and CodePlex just responding slowly to the massive SVN fetch that git svn clone requires.

Comment: I have the same problem with https://v8dotnet.codeplex.com/. It hangs for very long time and times out later without any certificate error. I am actually trying to create a fork on GitHub. Any help is appreciated.