# Error when trying to use svn2git on Windows

Tags: windows, svn, git

I am trying to import a svn repository into git on Windows 7. I have Ruby/Gems/svn2git installed, but when I run this command:

```
svn2git http://svn.server/path
```

I get the following error:

```
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/svn2git-2.0.0/lib/svn2git/migration.rb:226:i
n `popen': No such file or directory - git svn init --no-metadata --trunk=trunk
--tags=tags --branches=branches http://svn.server/path (Errno::ENO
ENT)
```

I don't know what this error means. All files are in the correct place as far as I can tell, and copying the repository to my local system doesn't work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: My SVN repository has the default trunk/branch structure.

Comment: just to be sure: you have `msysgit` installed?

Answer (score 0):

[Svn2Git documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/svn2git/2.0.0/file/README.markdown#Installation) states that depends on git-core (msysgit in windows) and git-svn, since the error is related to the "git svn" command, i guess you'll have to install it and make it available in your PATH.

Check [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350907/git-svn-on-windows-where-to-get-binaries) on how to install both git-core and git-svn.